# Show that $\sin(f)$ is a continuous mapping in $\mathcal{B}(M)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

> Show that $\sin:\mathcal{B}(M)\to \mathcal{B}(M)$ is a continuous mapping, where $\mathcal{B}(M)$ is the space of bounded real valued functions equipped with the $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty}$ sup norm.

**My approach:**

We already know that $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $h:=\sin(x)$ is a uniformly continuous function. So for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now we take two $f,g\in\mathcal{B}(M)$ such that $\Vert f-g\Vert_{\infty}<\delta$. This implies for all $x\in M$ that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\delta\implies |\sin(f(x))-\sin(g(x))|<\epsilon\implies \Vert \sin(f)-\sin(g)\Vert_{\infty}<\epsilon$.

---

Is this correct? I am a bit skeptical because it seems that we don't need the boundedness.

Comment: Boundedness of $f$ and $g$ ensure $\|f - g\|_\infty$ is finite.

Comment: You need also (to be a bit pedantic) to claim that if $f\in B(M)$ then $\sin(f)$ is also a member of that space.  That will use boundedness.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, Why? If $\sin$ wasn't a bounded function, then this would not invalidate the result $|f(x)-g(x)|<\delta\implies |\sin(f(x))-\sin(g(x))|<\epsilon\implies \Vert \sin(f)-\sin(g)\Vert_{\infty}<\epsilon$, I only used/needed the uniform continuity of $\sin$.

Comment: @Philipp  I posted an "answer" to illustrate the issue.  Your answer is fine if you simply add something like: "It is obvious that $\sin(f)\in B(M)$ whenever $f\in B(M)$."

Comment: @B.S.Thomson In your example you showed that a mapping $T_F$ doesn't necessarily map from $D[0,1]$ to $D[0,1]$ because the resulting function $f^2$ is no longer a derivative, that's ok. But I don't see how this relates to my problem.  As far as I have understood the question, we can assume that $\sin:\mathcal{B}(M)\to \mathcal{B}(M)$. The only thing we have to do is prove continuity and in my proof I did not use the boundedness of $\sin$ at any point.

Comment: @Philipp  You can "assume" in this case since it is true.  In general, however, any statement about a mapping between two spaces would normally require you to check that it is in fact  a mapping between those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The OP and I are debating a subtle point, too subtle for the tiny space of comments.

His solution of the problem is fine, but missing a necessary remark at least.  This "answer" just addresses that point.

1. For any bounded function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ define $\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}$.
2. Define $D[0,1]$ to be the linear  space of all bounded *derivatives* $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|_\infty$.  This is a normed linear space.  In fact it is a much-studied Banach space.  See reference [1].
3. Let  $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$  be a uniformly continuous function and  write  $T_F$ for the mapping $f\to F\circ f$,  i..e., this takes any real-valued function $f(x)$ and yields the function $F(f(x))$.

**Prove the *false* statement that $T_F$ is a continuous map from the space $D[0,1]$ to itself.**

*Copying from the OP:*

> We already know that $F:R→R$   is a uniformly continuous function. So
> for an arbitrary $ϵ>0$ we find a $δ>0$ such that for all $s,t∈R$ we
> have $|s-t|<δ⟹|F(s)−F(t)|<ϵ.$
>
> Now we take two $f,g∈D[0,1]$  such that $ ∥f−g∥_∞<δ$. This implies for all
> $x∈[0,1]$ that $|f(x)−g(x)|<δ⟹|F(f(x))−F(g(x))|<ϵ⟹∥T_F(f)−T_F(g)∥_∞<ϵ$.
> Thus $T_F$ is a continuous map.

**Spoiler**:  One can give an example of a function $f\in D[0,1]$ such that $f^2$ is not in $D[0,1]$.  In fact given any continuous, increasing function $F$  that is not linear there exists a bounded derivative $f$ such that $F\circ f$ is not a derivative.

---

REFERENCE:

[1] https://www.jstor.org/stable/44151124